# Is it necessary for a linear map to be an automorphism to allow polar decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, tensors

Bowen and Wang's Introduction to Vectors and Tensors I (pg. 168) states a general form of the polar decomposition theorem as

> Every automorphism **A** has two unique multiplicative decompositions
>   $$
> A = R U \quad  \text{and} \quad A = V R
> $$
>   where $R$ is unitary and $U, V$ are Hermitian and positive definite.

So clearly it is sufficient for $A$ to be an automorphism to allow a polar decomposition. But is this also a necessary condition?

If not, a counterexample would be welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It always exists (at least, for finite-dimensional spaces), after weakening positive-definite to positive-semidefinite, regardless of whether $A$ is invertible; it can be constructed from the singular value decomposition, for example. The decomposition is not unique if $A$ is singular, though; take the zero matrix for a trivial example.

Comment: Thanks. However, is it a necessary condition if one wants strict positive definiteness?

Comment: If $R$ is unitary and $U$ is positive definite, then $RU$ is invertible.